# Hide a Method from typescript Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

Is there away (annotation or any other method) to hide methods from Intellisense.

Comment: Why do you want to this? What are you trying to achieve? BTW you can mark the method `private` ...

Comment: The question is vauge, but I assume OP meant to hide it from Intellisense _suggestions_ - meaning you will _not_ get a compile error if you access it, but you also wont get it as a suggestion while typing. (Example `valueOf` method on primitive types.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use an interface to describe a reduced contract. Anything not described in the interface would effectively be hidden from auto-complete even though it is available on the class. This gives you the flexibility to decide when you want access to the property.

```
interface IReducedInterface {
    name: string;
}

class ExpandedClass implements IReducedInterface {
    public name: string;
    public hideFromIntellisense: string;
}

var example: IReducedInterface = new ExpandedClass();
```

If you type `example.` it will suggest `name` but not `hideFromIntellisense`.

You don't need to explicitly implement `IReducedInterface` as TypeScript is structurally typed.

Comment: How would you do this with arbitrary expanded and reduced interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this. But you can always walk into JavaScript, and typescript would not know:

```
class Test{
    member:string;

    visible(){
        this.member='visible';
    }
}

(<any>Test.prototype).notvisible = function(){ this.member ='notvisible'; }
```

[Try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Test%7B%0D%0A%09member%3astring;%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09visible%28%29%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.member=%27visible%27;%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%28%3Cany%3ETest.prototype%29.notvisible%20=%20function%28%29%7B%20this.member%20=%27notvisible%27;%20%7D)

Alternatively you could mark the function as private.

```
class Test{
    member:string;

    visible(){
        this.member='visible';
    }
    private notvisible(){
        this.member ='notvisible';
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with the "private soultion" is that there is no protected in typescript.